# How do I Debug in functions using Visual Studio Debugger in source maps

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, browserify, visual-studio-debugging, source-maps

The Setup:

Visual Studio 2013 update 5
I am using Task Runner Explorer and the below gulp file from recipes:

```
'use strict';
var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');

var customOpts = {
    entries: ['./app/controller.js'],
    debug: true
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts));

gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
      // log errors if they happen
      .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
      .pipe(buffer())
      // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })) // loads map from browserify file
         // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./',{includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../'})) // writes .map file
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
```

The below is from the html page containing a reference to my browserify bundled file:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
```

I get the following source Maps and bundle.
SourceMap:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js","app/controller.js","app/module.js"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;ACAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;;AClBA;AACA","file":"bundle.js","sourceRoot":"../"}
```

Bundle:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
require('./module.js');
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('myController', 

function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'test';

    activate();

    function activate() { }
});

function test() {
    var vm = 'test';
}

},{"./module.js":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
angular.module('app', []);

},{}]},{},[1])
```

I can debug successfully using the original files loaded through source maps in IE and chrome.

The Problem:

I cannot debug with script debugger within functions in the source mapped files but I can in the bundled file.

Scripts
[image: Scripts]

Can't Debug in function in controller.js but can debug outside of controller function
[image: Can't Debug in function in controller.js but can debug outside of controller function]

Can Debug Bundle.JS
[image: Can Debug in Bundlejs]

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Chrome and IE debugging works fine but a good percentage of our team debugs in visual studio.